# Best way to do USD math in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix

Pardon the n00b question!

I am trying to do some simple math in solidity using USD values.

For example, say the start price of a token offering is $0.50 USD and the contribution is $10.00 USD, then the number of tokens issued should be 20 tokens.

I am having trouble with the numbers with solidity.

Since Solidity doesn't use decimal places, I was assuming:

$0.50 USD would be represented as 0500000000000000000;
//0.500000000000000000

$10.00 USD would be represented as 10000000000000000000;
//10.000000000000000000000000

If I lead any unit values with zeros, Remix reports `Expected primary expression.` as the error.

What's the best way to do math if you need to account for decimal places in Solidity?

I am not looking to way any ETH, WEI math, just USD math accounting for at least 4 decimal places.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Just use cents instead of dollars.  It is usually a bad idea to use fraction numbers for money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this so you don't have to count zeros all day:

```
function test() public pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 amount = 10 * 10**18;
    uint256 price = 0.5 * 10**18;

    assert(amount / price == 20);
}
```

Comment: Would this method be at risk of any overflows? Is there an equivalent way using SafeMath.sol?

Comment: The code I shared can't overflow, because the only numbers in it are literals known at compile-time. In general, 2^256 is about 10^77, so you can safely multiply a number by 10^18 as long as the number never exceeds 10^59. 10^59 is a lot of dollars. :-) If you are accepting untrusted numbers from outside your contract, just `require` them to be in a reasonable range.